# Restricting virtual address range of a process?

Tags: virtual-memory

On Linux x86_64, I have a simple application for which I track all memory accesses with Intel's PIN. The program uses only "a bit" of memory, most of it for dynamically allocated matrices (I've bisected the right value with `ulimit`). However, the memory accesses span the whole range of the VM address space, low addresses for what I presume global variables in the code, high addresses for the `malloc()ed` arrays.
There's a huge gap in the middle, and even in the high addresses the range is between 0x7fff4e1a37f4 and 0x7fea3af99000, which is much larger than what I would assume my application to use in total.

The post-processing that I need to do on the memory accesses deals very badly with these sparse accesses, so I'm looking for a way to restrict the virtual address range available to the process so that "it just fits", and accesses will show addresses between 0 and some more reasonable value for dynamically allocated memory (somewhere around the 40 Mb that I've discovered through `ulimit`).

---

Q: Is there an easy way to limit the available address space (and hence implicitly, available memory) to an individual process on Linux, ideally from the command line on a per-process basis?

---

Further notes:

- I can link my application statically.
- Even if I limit the memory with ulimit, the process still uses the full VM address range (not entirely unexpected).
- I know about /proc/${pid}/maps, but would like to avoid creating wrappers to deal with this, and how to actually use the data in there.
- I've heard about `prelink` (which may not apply to my static binary, but only libraries?) and can image that there are more intrusive ways to interfere with `malloc()`, but these solutions are too far out of my expertise to evaluate their usefulness ([Limiting the heap area's Virtual address range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32905284/60462), https://stackoverflow.com/a/29960208/60462)
- If there's no simple command line-solution, instead of going for any elaborate hack, I'll probably just wing it in the post-processing and "normalize" the addresses e.g. via a few lines of perl).

Answer (score 0):

ld.so(8) lists `LD_PREFER_MAP_32BIT_EXEC` as a way to restrict the address space to the lower 2GiB which is significantly less than the normal 64-bit address space, but possibly not small enough for your purposes.

It may also be possible to use the prctl(2) `PR_SET_MM` options to control the addresses of different parts of the program to solve your problem.